# How do I update the documentation on someone elses module?

Tags: 7, community-official-site

I want to update the documentation on the [Agenda](http://drupal.org/project/agenda) module on Drupal to provide a bit more clarity on how to get it set up.

I have contacted the author and he said great!

How do I do this on drupal.org?  I see the code can be changed via git, is the documentation part of the git repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation pages on drupal.org are normal Drupal nodes. You need special permissions in order to edit these nodes. There is documentation on drupal.org about [how to contribute to documentation](http://drupal.org/node/700538).

If the module in question includes a README.txt file, then you can [submit a patch](http://drupal.org/patch/submit) to the module maintainers that includes the updates. If the module doesn't have a README.txt file, then submit a patch that adds one.

Comment: How do I become a module maintainer?

Comment: Anyone can contribute a module via their Drupal Sandbox. In order to promote a sandbox project to a full project you have to pass a code review process. If you want to become a maintainer of an existing project, you have to request co-maintainership from the module's current maintainers, usually via a ticket in the module's issue queue. IIRC, you still have to pass the code review to get access to maintaining an existing full project.  All this is covered in the "Getting Involved Guide" on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/contribute/development

Answer (score 1):

## Module docu that gets installed with a module

For documentation that gets installed with a module, you need to get something "included" in a module as it is downloaded from drupal.org (such as the .zip or .tar files).

That is why you need something like a patch file, and then you have to wait/hope for it to get committed by a module (co-)maintainer (if you are not one of them).

Examples of this type of docu are the `readme.txt` file, or docu that uses the format provided by the [Advanced help](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module.

## Module docu published as community documentation

The ***community documentation*** pages is something that anybody (logged in to drupal.org) can contribute to without the need for a module (co-)maintainer to "accept" the patch (as is the case for the [Advanced help](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_help) module approach). Obviously, creating such docu is just a matter of create/update of relevant nodes on drupal.org (there are no patches involved).

The only (minor I think) challenge is to locate the best spot for the top (parent level) of the "community pages to be created". Once you figured that out (or you found some already existing docu for the module you want to contribute to), just create a child page of the parent page you want it to be a child of.

For community docu there is 1 (optional, but important) task that needs to be completed by the module (co-)maintainers: add a "link" to the top of the community docu of that module within the "resources" of the project page. That will create the "Read documentation" link on the project page. Only module maintainers have that autorisation. So if you created community docu, or find existing docu which is not mentioned on the project page, then create an issue for getting that fixed.

## Pros and cons

The advantage of community docu, as compared to module docu installed with a module, is that it can be accessed by potential users of the module (compare to "promotion material"?), who have not yet installed the module. As compared to [Advanced help](https://www.drupal.org/project/advanced_help) which is only accessible for users that already installed the module (compare to admin/user guides for the module). Obvious, both types of docu serve different purposes. So any time docu is created, one should decided about "where it should be included in".