# How can I add a new module to existing Examples Module?

Tags: community-official-site

I have created a **New Drupal 8 Module** that could be added to existing [Examples Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples). So, How I can proceed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I update the documentation on someone elses module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28757/how-do-i-update-the-documentation-on-someone-elses-module). This is a duplicate because the linked question generically answers "How do I contribute to a module" by linking to http://drupal.org/node/700538 and http://drupal.org/patch/submit

Comment: I think these are 2 different questions: one is asking about contribution on d.o. vs. contribution on a module project. They might have some overlap, but the intent is different.

Comment: mradcliffe: Links shared by you are specifically regarding documentation and patches contribution. Possibly that would help me in future contribution aspects. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you so much on starting on this! Examples module have helped many developers overcome the Google fail!

And contributing to it is pretty easy. Personally, to add the module to the main module, I would follow the steps below:

1. Create a sandbox project with the name **foo_example** (*foo* being the nature of your module.
2. Check if the module satisfies the checklist : https://www.drupal.org/node/2209627
3. Create an issue in the issue queue with

   - Title : Add foo_example to the D8 repo.
   - Category : Plan
   - Version : 8.x-1.x-dev
   - Component : Other
   - Status : Needs Review
4. Inside the body give a description of what your module does, link it to the sandbox project.

Next, you wait for the reviews :) You might get it reviewed by your peers or friends/IRC so that some obvious issues are spotted on early. And the maintainers of the examples module should be able to review it. And you should also get credits for your work!

Comment: Thanks! This seems promising, would submit the code following above steps.

Comment: @user3542174 Sure thing! Let me know if you need further help. I am AjitS on Freenode IRC.